# Spring Kafka Embedded - topic already exists between tests

Tags: java, spring-kafka, junit5

I created a group of test (JUnit 5) with embedded kafka (spring-kafka-test), and when I run them sometimes (not always) I got "**Topic 'some_name' already exists**" on one or more test in single run.

All tests are use the same name of topic (I don't want to change that name for every test), test class has DirtiesContext annotation (AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD). I not sure what is the cause of this problem, and how to solve it.

```
@SpringBootTest
@EmbeddedKafka(partitions = 1, topics = {"some_name"}, ports = 9092)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class RemovalKafkaTestIT {
    private EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafkaBroker = new EmbeddedKafkaBroker(1, true, TOPIC);
    private final static String SERVER_ADDRES = "127.0.0.1:9092";

    private Consumer<String, String> prepareConsumer() {
        Map<String, Object> configsConsumer = new HashMap<>(KafkaTestUtils.consumerProps("consumer", "false", embeddedKafkaBroker));
        configsConsumer.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        configsConsumer.put("bootstrap.servers", SERVER_ADDRES);
        Consumer<String, String> consumer = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(configsConsumer, new StringDeserializer(), new StringDeserializer()).createConsumer();
        consumer.subscribe(singleton("some_name"));
        return consumer;
    }

    @Test
    public void someMethodWithKafka1() {
        // some logic
        ...
        // check topic content 
        Consumer<String, String> consumer = this.prepareConsumer();
        embeddedKafkaBroker.consumeFromEmbeddedTopics(consumer, "some_name");

        ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = KafkaTestUtils.getRecords(consumer);
        assertThat(records.count()).isEqualTo(1); // and other checks :)

        // clean
        consumer.commitSync();
        consumer.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void someMethodWithKafka2() {
        // some other logic
        ...
        // check topic content 
        Consumer<String, String> consumer = this.prepareConsumer();
        embeddedKafkaBroker.consumeFromEmbeddedTopics(consumer, "some_name");

        ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = KafkaTestUtils.getRecords(consumer);
        assertThat(records.count()).isEqualTo(1); // and other checks :)

        // clean
        consumer.commitSync();
        consumer.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have just the one test file with the EmbeddedKafka or do you have other test classes doing the same thing?

Comment: Only one file with few tests cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two brokers; one you create yourself:

```
private EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafkaBroker = new EmbeddedKafkaBroker(1, true, TOPIC);
```

and one managed by Spring:

```
@SpringBootTest
@EmbeddedKafka(partitions = 1, topics = {"some_name"}, ports = 9092)
```

When you use `@EmbeddedKafka` with a Spring test context; the broker is added to the context.

Change it to

```
@Autowired
private EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafkaBroker;
```

and don't add another bean.

Generally, it's easier (and faster) to use a different topic for each test; avoiding creating a broker for each test.

**EDIT**

> `ports = 9092`

Use a random port instead (omit this configuration) and use

```
configsConsumer.put("bootstrap.servers", this.embeddedKafkaBroker.getBrokersAsString());
```

Comment: Problem still occurs. And as I said before, I don't want to use multiple topics in tests.

Comment: See the edit to my answer; you should not use a fixed port for each instance. Understand, though, that your tests will take much longer to run when using a new broker for each test.

Comment: Still, after remove port from class annotation and set a port by using getBrokersAsString() in code I get same error (randomly).

Comment: That makes no sense; if each instance gets a new port it's impossible for the topic to already exist. Something else is going on.

Comment: You know, it's workin, so probably I did somethink wrong in friday. Thank you.
But still this is only workaround problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try marking your `EmbeddedKafkaBroker` as a bean or using `@Autowire` to create the broker from the top level annotation.

Because the broker isn't marked as a bean its lifecycle won't get managed by the application context and it won't get cleaned up between runs from `@DirtiesContext`. Maybe it is holding on to something that keeps the topic around across test boundaries.

Comment: Problem still exist after creating EmbeddedKafkaBroker as Bean in Configuration and Auwired in to test class.

Answer (score 0):

Remove @DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)

Comment: I assume you are referring to the annotation of class `RemovalKafkaTestIT`. If so, then perhaps you could [edit] your answer and add some explanation as to how removing the annotation solves the problem. By the way (and not directly related to your answer), I suggest that you learn how to use [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).